# How to join data with static dataset in SQL

Tags: sql

In DB I have fields like `name, ENUM`, where `ENUM` is varchar and could be: heigh, medium, low.

I need to sort data by ENUM but by priority level (like `high -> medium -> low`).

I cannot create table in DB with which I can perform join, so my question is it possible to define dynamic mapping in SQL query (like high is 2, medium is 1, low is 0) and then sort by ints?

Comment: [edit] to tag _which_ SQL you are using and show some example input data and desired output data.

Comment: Try this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/case-when-in-postgresql

Comment: @kometen thanks for reference! I've never before used this construction in sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
order by (case enum when 'high' then 1 when 'medium' then 2
                    when 'low' then 3 else 4
          end)
```

Some databases have specialized functions that simplify this.  As an example, MySQL has `field()`:

```
order by field(enum, 'high', 'medium', 'low')
```

Or, if you wanted to get the right ordering but with inscrutable code, you could use the *last* letter:

```
order by right(enum, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, the first option helped me!